# haveMany through add and edit CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have three tables: `recipes`, `ingredients` `ingredients_recipes` it is clear that they are found to manage *many to many* normalized relationship.

However, the `ingredients_recipes` structure is like the following:

```
id: int primary key auto increment
recipe_id
ingredient_id
amount
```

My issue is with the `amount` field. When adding new recipe I could able to see a multiple select menu with all ingredients but I could not able to manage how could I add the `amount` value for each ingredient selected. The result after adding in the `ingredients_recipes` table an `amount` field with null value!

what could I can do in the `add` view to make an amount input text related with the ingredient chosen from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have a IngredientsRecipe model, right?

HABTM relations in cake are the best, if you only want to store that, the relation. But if you also want to add other values to that table, you need to create a new model and treat it as you would treat any table.

You have this:

```
Recipe Model
   HABTM Ingredient
Ingredient Model
   HABTM Recipe
```

You will have to change it to

```
(new) IngredientsRecipe Model
   belongsTo Recipe
   belongsTo Ingredient

Recipe Model
   hasMany IngredientsRecipe 
Ingredient Model
   hasMany IngredientsRecipe
```

It is mentioned in the documentation as [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

PD: If you don't like the IngredientsRecipe name, just put one that's appropriate, like Amount or something, and then just change the table with [useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) in the model. I've found that DoctorsPatientsRemediesEtc or similar are a headache to have as a model name.

Comment: Already I have `IngredientRecipe` model. However, each of `Recipe` and `Ingredient` models still has HABTM relations, so, do you mean that I have to remove HABTM from them?

Comment: yes, because you'll be treating `IngredientRecipe` as an ordinary table, like having Users hasmany Groups hasMany Projects, in that case you treat Group as a common model, not just an association.